# Do xsl/xslt 1.0 have features to check some straightforward conditions in xml files?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT 1.0 to check some conditions against my xml files. The conditions are something like that:

- value of a particular-path element has unique values
- value of a particular-path element contains only the values from another fixed-path value
- value of a particular-path element must be from a fix range of numbers

I can see that we can always approach these conditions from the brute force method as we can extract any value and basic arithmetic is there to build up the conditions. But I'm interested to find out if there are keywords/functions supported in XSLT 1.0 to simplify the checks?

Comment: Please ask one *specific* question at a time and provide a [mcve]. In general, all the functions supported by XSLT 1.0 are listed in the XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 specifications .In addition, some XSLT 1.0 processors support some extension functions.

Comment: Such restrictions seem to fall more in the area of validation with schemas like XSD or Schematron than into the XSLT are of transformation. Perhaps you can show us some concrete examples and how your "brute force method" would look. Is the restriction to XSLT 1 given because you know XSLT/XPath 2.0 features like `(1 to 5)` or ('a', 'b', 'c')` or `distinct-values` that you don't consider brute force? Or are you new to the whole XSLT world but restricted to an XSLT 1 processor? In the latter case, check support for EXSLT extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:

> • value of a particular-path element has unique values

consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>Alpha</child>
        <child>Bravo</child>
        <child>Charlie</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>Delta</child>
        <child>Alpha</child>
        <child>Echo</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

To test if all values of `/root/parent/child` are unique, you can do:

**in pure XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="child" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="not(parent/child[count(key('child', .)) > 1])" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**with support for the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(parent/child)=count(set:distinct(parent/child))" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Please post your other questions separately.

Comment: Thanks, looks like EXSLT is supported for me, so I'll go ahead and try other two conditions. I can see set:difference(), math:max() kind of functions in EXSLT, which is kind of cool

Answer (score 0):

Your three examples can all be done in XSLT 1.0, but XML Schema is probably more appropriate for this job.